# Laravel Echo Server - Socket.io - Polling fails

Tags: laravel, sockets, socket.io, laravel-echo

The Laravel Echo Server is launched via:

`laravel-echo-server start` and is running fine:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.3.1

Starting server...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

CHANNEL private-user:09222583-ef73-5640-bcc8-062b36c4f380.d3d0a4d2-0c95-5f5f-aea4-1dfe1fa36483
```

However, in the front-end, the polling seems to fail. The Network tab shows that requests keep trying to connnect and fail:

[image]

The URLs look like this:
`https://example.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MGEIXhf`

The `laravel-echo-server.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "authHost": "https://example.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "password": "56df4h5dfg4"
        }
    },
    "devMode": false,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "/etc/nginx/ssl/example_com/ssl-bundle.crt",
    "sslKeyPath": "/etc/nginx/ssl/example_com/example_com.key",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": ""
}
```

The port `6001` seems to be open in the `ufw`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
...
6001                       ALLOW       Anywhere
...
6001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
...
```

Comment: Did you manage to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you used same port number in js file also.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'socket.io',
host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. On my local setup everything worked fine but on the staging, droplet `ufw` was blocking every incoming request `/var/log/ufw.log` showed them all being blocked. I already had 6001 open in `ufw`, and I'd even given my IP access to everything in `ufw`, but requests were still blocked.

Although I really didn't want the security risk, I briefly disabled `ufw` and everything started working, connections were made instantly, no timeouts. I then quickly enabled `ufw` again, and everything continued working. I tested new connections in other browsers - all working.

So although it's really bad advice to try turning the firewall off and on again, it did work for me.

I hope someone else might chime in with a way to diagnose and fix such `UFW` issues in a secure way.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the cause of the problem in my situation.

The first rule I'd set up with ufw was to allow ssh traffic.
I then installed fail2ban and part of that process saved the iptables using iptables-persistent.

When I later added a ufw rule to allow 6001 everything was working.

After a reboot 6001 stopped being open even though it was listed as open in ufw's status output - the reason it wasn't working was the iptables had been restored with the copy taken before the 6001 rule was added.

So if you've got iptables-persistent running make sure you use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```

after adding any new ufw rules.